# How can i add query parameter to BigQuery add connect it to Data Studio?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

In BQ I have saved view that connected to Data Studio. I need to add a parameter field to this view and control it from Data Studio.

Adding a dropdown list doesn't work, there is some complex calculations in BQ, i'm not getting the result i expected.

How i tried. Query, for example:

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
```

I added query parameter like this:

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where subject = @subject
```

Then in Data Studio I added parameter field. But i'm getting this error message:

```
BigQuery error: Parameters are not supported; failed to parse view
```

How can I add parameter and connect view to Data Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [custom queries](https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-bigquery-parameters-data-studio/):

- Choose `Custom Query` in BigQuery connector in Data Studio

[image]

- Add the field as a parameter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery + DataStudio does support Query Parameter (as introduced here https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-bigquery-parameters-data-studio/).

However, BigQuery itself doesn't support using using query parameter inside view definition. For now, you will have to leave the filter outside of the view.